# Flex: Using multiple CSS "style names" in one control?

Tags: css, apache-flex

I have this control, `mx:Text`, and I want to assign its `htmlText` member w/something like:

```
<div class="style_header">This text will have, say, Courier as its font</div>
<div class="style_body">And this one will be, oh I dunno, cuneiform</div>
```

Then, in the AS I had:

```
var oCSSHeader:CSSStyleDeclaration = new CSSStyleDeclaration;
var oCSSBody:CSSStyleDeclaration = new CSSStyleDeclaration;
oCSSHeader.setStyle('font-size', '12');
oCSSHeader.setStyle('font-family', 'Courier');
oCSSBody.setStyle('font-size', '14');
oCSSBody.setStyle('font-family', 'Cuneiform');
StyleManager.setStyleDeclaration('.style_header', oCSSHeader, true);
StyleManager.setStyleDeclaration('.style_body', oCSSBody, true);
```

Whatever I set the sizes and families to, both sets of text look exactly the same. I looked at examples and realized that you probably have to set an entire control to one style name. Which means

```
<mx:Text id="messageText" width="100%" styleName="style_header" />
```

should have worked, but it didn't! So what am I doing wrong? I'm not getting any error message or anything. And is it even possible to set different style names w/in one control?

I'm running Flex 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Try `Text.styleSheet`,

**Example:**

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function getHtmlTextStyle():StyleSheet
        {
            var style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
            style.setStyle(".style_header", {fontSize: "12px", fontFamily: 'Courier'});
            style.setStyle(".style_body", {fontSize: "14px", fontFamily:"Cuneiform"});
            return style;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:Text id="messageText" width="100%" styleSheet="{getHtmlTextStyle()}">
    <mx:htmlText>
        <![CDATA[
        <p class="style_header">This text will have, say, Courier as its font</p>
        <p class="style_body">And this one will be, oh I dunno, cuneiform</p>
        ]]>
    </mx:htmlText>
</mx:Text>
```

The Style in Flex application is not doesn't apply to `htmlText`.
They are actually separated and not much related but just using the same syntax.

Also,

Tags allowed in `Text.htmlText` are very limited. `<div>` tag will not work, for example. See the [document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d52.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d48) for more information.